# icpc slower than gcc?

Tags: opencv, gcc, parallel-processing, icc, intel-parallel-studio

I'm trying to make an optimized parallel version of [opencv SURF](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html) and in particular [surf.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xfeatures2d/src/surf.cpp) using Intel C++ compiler.

I'm using Intel Advisor to locate inefficient and unvectorized loops. In particular, it suggests to rebuild the code using the `icpc` compiler (instead of `gcc`) and then to use the `xCORE-AVX2` flag since it's available for my hardware.

So my original `cmake` for building opencv  using `g++` was:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=... -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=... -DWITH_TBB=OFF -DWITH_OPENMP=ON
```

And built the application which uses SURF with `g++ ... -O3 -g -fopenmp`

Using `icpc` instead is:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=... -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=... -DWITH_TBB=OFF -DWITH_OPENMP=ON -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=icc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=icpc -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-debug inline-debug-info -parallel-source-info=2 -ipo -parallel -xCORE-AVX2 -Bdynamic"
```

(in particular notice `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`)

And compiled the SURF application with: `-g -O3 -ipo -parallel -qopenmp -xCORE-AVX2` and `-shared-intel -parallel` for linking

I thought that the `icpc` solution was going to be faster than the `g++` one, but it isn't: `icpc` takes 0.15s while `g++` takes `0.12`s (I ran the experiments several times and these numbers are reliable).

Why this happens? Am I doing something wrong with `icpc`?

**g++ OpenCV compiling options (partially generated by cmake):**

```
-fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -Wstrict-prototypes  -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith  -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-undef -Wno-unused -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-cast-align -Wno-shadow -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-pointer-to-int-cast -Wno-int-to-pointer-cast -Wno-unused-parameter -fPIC -O2 -g -DNDEBUG
```

**icpc OpenCV compiling options (partially generated by cmake):**

```
-fsigned-char -fp-model precise -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-unused-but-set-parameter -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-unused -Wno-shadow -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -fPIC -O2 -g -DNDEBUG
```

There is thing that I noticed: the `icpc` flags that I specified are not included. Theoretically the following command in `cmake`:

-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-debug inline-debug-info -parallel-source-info=2 -ipo -parallel -xCORE-AVX2 -Bdynamic"

Should add all these flags during `make` but running `VERBOSE=1` it shows only the flags that I posted in **icpc OpenCV compiling options (partially generated by cmake)**. This is weird also because the `cmake` execution is finished, this is one of the lines of the report:

```
--     C++ Compiler:                /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.132/linux/bin/intel64/icpc  (ver 17.0.1.20161005)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -debug inline-debug-info -parallel-source-info=2 -ipo -parallel -xCORE-AVX2 -Bdynamic   -fsigned-char -fp-model precise -qopenmp -O3 -DNDEBUG 
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -debug inline-debug-info -parallel-source-info=2 -ipo -parallel -xCORE-AVX2 -Bdynamic   -fsigned-char -fp-model precise -qopenmp -g 
--     C Compiler:                  /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.132/linux/bin/intel64/icc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -fp-model precise -qopenmp -O3 -DNDEBUG 
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -fp-model precise -qopenmp -g
```

As you can see, the optimization flags that I included in `DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` appears in `C++ (Debug/Release)` but they don't when I run `make VERBOSE=1` and I don't know why.

Btw, from my knowledge, `icpc` should produce always faster code than `g++` (if they use the same options, as in this case). Why this happens?

Comment: Could you please post 2 lines :
1) all compilation options for g++ 
2) all compilation options for icpc

Comment: @Arseniy I updated it, is that what you wanted? :)

Comment: Please add also g++ options

Comment: Ehm I added them in g++ OpenCV compiling options (partially generated by cmake)