# Intel Compiler: warning #11021: unresoved Referenced in

Tags: parallel-processing, icc, intel-parallel-studio

I built [opencv](http://opencv.org) with the following cmake options:

```
cmake  -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DWITH_TBB=OFF -DWITH_OPENMP=ON -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=icc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=icpc -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-debug inline-debug-info -parallel-source-info=2 -ipo -parallel -xCORE-AVX2 -Bdynamic" ..
```

However, when I try to build (with `icpc`) the application which uses opencv (built with `icpc`) these warning messages appears:

```
icpc -shared-intel -L/home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib -parallel -o "SURFAllInOne"  ./main.o ./surf.o   -lopencv_core -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gzeof
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_core.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gzrewind
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_core.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gzopen
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_core.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gzclose
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_core.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gzgets
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_core.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gzputs
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_core.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNK2cv9Feature2D14descriptorSizeEv
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZN2cv9Feature2D4readERKNS_8FileNodeE
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNK2cv9Feature2D14descriptorTypeEv
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZN2cv9Feature2D7computeERKNS_11_InputArrayERSt6vectorINS_8KeyPointESaIS5_EERKNS_12_OutputArrayE
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZTTN2cv9Feature2DE
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZN2cv15KeyPointsFilter16runByImageBorderERSt6vectorINS_8KeyPointESaIS2_EENS_5Size_IiEEi
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZN2cv15KeyPointsFilter10retainBestERSt6vectorINS_8KeyPointESaIS2_EEi
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZN2cv9Feature2DD2Ev
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZN2cv9Feature2D16detectAndComputeERKNS_11_InputArrayES3_RSt6vectorINS_8KeyPointESaIS5_EERKNS_12_OutputArrayEb
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZN2cv15KeyPointsFilter16removeDuplicatedERSt6vectorINS_8KeyPointESaIS2_EE
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZN2cv9Feature2D6detectERKNS_11_InputArrayERSt6vectorINS_8KeyPointESaIS5_EES3_
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZN2cv9Feature2D6detectERKNS_11_InputArrayERSt6vectorIS4_INS_8KeyPointESaIS5_EESaIS7_EES3_
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZTIN2cv9Feature2DE
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZN2cv9Feature2D7computeERKNS_11_InputArrayERSt6vectorIS4_INS_8KeyPointESaIS5_EESaIS7_EERKNS_12_OutputArrayE
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNK2cv9Feature2D5emptyEv
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNK2cv9Feature2D11defaultNormEv
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNK2cv9Feature2D5writeERNS_11FileStorageE
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZN2cv15KeyPointsFilter15runByPixelsMaskERSt6vectorINS_8KeyPointESaIS2_EERKNS_3MatE
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_file_chooser_set_do_overwrite_confirmation
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_mutex_lock
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_main_iteration
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_window_resize
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_get_current_time
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_file_chooser_set_current_name
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_type_check_instance_cast
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_widget_destroy
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_window_fullscreen
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_mutex_unlock
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_box_pack_end
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_widget_get_colormap
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_cond_broadcast
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_box_pack_start
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gdk_cairo_set_source_pixbuf
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_signal_connect_data
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_widget_add_events
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_window_set_title
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved cairo_paint
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_free
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_dialog_run
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gdk_window_move_resize
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_range_set_range
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_source_remove
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_range_get_type
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_main_iteration_do
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_cond_new
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_init
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_file_chooser_add_filter
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_range_set_value
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_window_get_title
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_cond_timed_wait
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_file_filter_new
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_thread_yield
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_return_if_fail_warning
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_window_set_geometry_hints
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_window_set_resizable
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_widget_queue_resize
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_widget_get_events
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_file_chooser_set_filter
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_label_new
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_dialog_get_type
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_file_filter_add_pattern
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_time_val_add
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_object_get_type
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_box_get_type
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gdk_window_set_user_data
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_window_move
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_widget_new
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_file_chooser_get_type
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_container_get_type
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_type_class_peek
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_widget_get_visual
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_file_chooser_get_filename
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_type_register_static_simple
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_scale_set_draw_value
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_widget_get_window
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_vbox_new
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_range_get_value
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gdk_cairo_create
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_style_set_background
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_type_check_class_cast
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_thread_new
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_timeout_add
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_file_filter_set_name
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gdk_window_new
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_hbox_new
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_object_unref
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_type_check_instance_is_a
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_events_pending
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_window_new
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_scale_get_type
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_window_unfullscreen
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_usleep
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_widget_queue_draw
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_thread_self
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_widget_show
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_widget_get_realized
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_hscale_new_with_range
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_container_add
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_cond_wait
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved cairo_destroy
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_scale_set_digits
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_window_get_type
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_widget_get_type
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_style_attach
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved g_mutex_new
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved gtk_widget_set_realized
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved deflateParams
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved inflate
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved deflateReset
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved inflateInit_
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved deflateInit_
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved inflateReset
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved deflate
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved uncompress
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved deflateEnd
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved compress
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved inflateSync
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved inflateEnd
        Referenced in /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/originalOpenCV/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
```

What does this means? The code is correct but I wonder if I should bother about this (especially if this make the code slower, I talk about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42238022/icpc-slower-than-gcc))

Comment: In my experience these warnings affect the performance for sure. If there are these warnings then the performance is as you haven't specified the -ipo option (This is observed only and haven't validated it well enough).

Comment: @warunapww thanks for your comment. And how this can be resolved usually?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this has been an issue for a long time in Intel compilers when you use it with `-ipo` ([inter procedural optimizations](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522667)) flag. This is a known [issue](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/ipo-warning-11021-unresolved-symbols-referenced-a-dynamic-library). The issue surfaces when the libraries you use also build with **other** libraries. But we do not explicitly list these **other** libraries when we build our application. In fact you don't have to. But inter-procedural analysis fail to figure out these **other** libraries and therefore the analysis fails resulting not producing any optimizations related to -ipo. Therefore, the degrade in possible/achievable performance.

The workaround is to list all the libraries used (transitively) in the compilation command of your application using `-l`.

For example, let's say my application needs an library A (`liba`) and `liba` was compiled with libraries B (`libb`) and C (`libc`).

Usually at link time of our application we specify `-lliba` in our command. But with -`ipo` compiler option this is not enough. You also have to specify `-llibb -llibc` in your compilation command as well.

**Find the libraries:** 
You can start either from your make file or from the warning message
i.e. your warning message listed following libs: `libopencv_core.so, libopencv_xfeatures2d.so, libopencv_highgui.so` and `libopencv_imgcodecs.so`

Then for each lib run `ldd libname`
This will give you the list of libs referred by `libname` library. You have to recursively run this command for all the libs you found. You can skip the system libs such as "libc.so, linux-vdso.so" etc...

for example, when I try ldd on papi library

```
ldd libpapi.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe7a799000)
    libpfm.so.4 => path to lib/libpfm.so.4 (0x00007fa2fd1c3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa2fcd98000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000056413361c000)
```

Here, libpfm.so is the interesting one. Rest of the libs are system libs. Then we run `ldd` on libpfm.so

```
ldd libpfm.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc5df9d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007faf97e74000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000561984fdb000)
```

This only refer to system libs, therefore we can stop our algorithm here.

At the end here is the list of libs: papi and pfm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but have you seen how many libraries are there? And I don't know even know if I have or how to find them

Comment: I tried your method but the warnings remain. I compiled with `ifort -c -O3 -static -ipo -lhdf5_fortran invmondays.f90` but I get a list of errors similar to `ipo: warning #11021: unresolved H5Dcreate2
        Referenced in libhdf5_fortran.a(H5Df.o)`

Comment: @Manfredo unfortunately I have only tested this on C programs with icc compiler

Comment: @justHelloWorld There are only 4 distinct libraries, it can be done manually or with a simple script would do.